# How to call a function of a php file from an include(.inc) file?

Tags: php, include

The code which I tried is:

**example.php**

```
function test() 
{
    echo "Function is called";
}
```

**test_include.inc**

```
include_once("example.php");
test();
```

Comment: So what is the problem

Comment: @SunilPachlangia when i tried this code, function is not called

Comment: And how it is this related with cakephp?

Comment: Make sure your example.php file is duly included, using require_once();. If it is not included it will trigger an error.

Comment: Change `include_once()` to `require_once()` and see if there is an error.

Comment: @gmponos sorry sir. that has been chosen mistakely

Comment: change the name of the file to *.php.inc

Comment: Change file name from test_include.inc to test_include.inc.php or simply test_include.php

Comment: So are you loading test_include.inc in your browser? Is your configuration set up to interpret .inc files using the PHP parser? Looks to me like you have your file names crossed.

Comment: @gmponos its not working when i changed filename as u said

Comment: @JasonMcCreary there is no error throwed. Also function doesn't work

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles no i will include test_include.inc on another php to reuse the code

Comment: Is that how you're it, by including the test_include.inc in a third, unspecified, file? Does that third file have a .php extension?

Comment: yes that 3rd file where i include "test_include.inc" is a php file.. @bloodyKnuckles

Comment: I ran a test with a third PHP file containing simply `<?php include('test_include.inc'); ?>`, loaded that third file in my browser, and I got the text "Function is called" in my browser page. That works so we need more information to find out where the error is. By the way, be sure all your PHP code in every file is wrapped in `<?php ... ?>` tags, and all the files are in the same directory.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles i use different directories only. I have checked directory's path. There is no mistake in it.

Answer (score 0):

@arun-kumar, You should have the function declared in the test_include.inc and include that in your example.php. As example.php is the file that would be executed. But you could also include a php file in another php file or an inc file in another inc file.

Comment: So there is no way to execute a php function from a include file?